# Change textbox value dynamically?

Tags: vb.net, variables, dynamic

I have 7 textboxes named lblSun, lblMon etc and 7 buttons named cmdSun, cmdMon etc. I want to change the Text value of these text boxes and buttons from within the query. I've tried `Me.Controls("cmd" & daysOfWeek(i)).Text`, but it does not work.

The error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub loadSchedule()
    ' days of week
    Dim daysOfWeek(0 To 6) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim var As String
    Dim ctrl As Control
    ' set up the days of the week
    daysOfWeek(0) = "Sun"
    daysOfWeek(1) = "Mon"
    daysOfWeek(2) = "Tue"
    daysOfWeek(3) = "Wed"
    daysOfWeek(4) = "Thu"
    daysOfWeek(5) = "Fri"
    daysOfWeek(6) = "Sat"
    ' connect to the db
    Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Form1.conString)
    con.Open()
    ' query stuff
    Dim query As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim rs As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    ' loop
    For i = LBound(daysOfWeek) To UBound(daysOfWeek)
        ' set query
        query = "SELECT * FROM Schedule WHERE Employee=" & employee & " AND ScheduleDay='" & daysOfWeek(i) & "'"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' var
        var = "cmd" & daysOfWeek(i)
        ' any results?
        If rs.HasRows = True Then
            ' get it
            rs.Read()
            ' show it baby
            'Controls("lbl" & daysOfWeek(i)).Text = rs.Item("TimeIn") & " - " & rs.Item("TimeOut")
            Me.Controls("cmd" & daysOfWeek(i) & "").Text = "Edit"
        Else
            ' show it baby
            Controls("lbl" & daysOfWeek(i)).Text = "RDO"
            Controls("cmd" & daysOfWeek(i)).Text = "New"
        End If
    Next
    ' close db
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have your buttons sitting on a Panel?

Comment: They're placed within a table (docked), on a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the controls in `Me.Controls` which don't exist, because the buttons/textboxes are inside a table.

You should use :

```
table.Controls("cmd" & daysOfWeek(i)).Text = "Edit"
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I can't believe it was something so simple!